# How does [System.DateTime]::Now.ToString() interpret a string?

Tags: datetime, powershell

I've noticed the following code:

```
[System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("dd month yyyy")
```

produces the following output:

```
12 12onP2 2014
```

"dd" correctly shows today's date which is the 12th, and "yyyy" correctly displays 2014.

But why does "m" output 12, and "th" outputs "P2"?

(Today is the 12th of June 2014 btw). 
I'm aware that the I should use:

```
[System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
```

however I'm more interested in how it's interpreting this string input, not what the correct string to use is.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformat.cs#da095f353f2ade5d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Custom DateTime specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) are only single or repeated characters. Words like `month` aren't recognized collectively as having special meaning.

It's instead treated as 4 separate parts by its characters:

- `m` = `"12"` = *The minute, from 0 through 59.*
- `on` = `"on"` = (via "Any other character") *The character is copied to the result string unchanged.*
- `t` = `"P"` = *The first character of the AM/PM designator.*
- `h` = `"2"` = *The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12.*

Answer (score 3):

```
month
```

is interpreted as a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), where each character combination has a special meaning;

From the page above;

> **"m" The minute, from 0 through 59.** The minute is 12, so it outputs "12".
>   "on" has no meaning, either in combination or individually, so outputs "on".
>   **"t"` The first character of the AM/PM designator.** It's PM, so it outputs "P".
>   **"h" The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12.** It's 2PM, so it outputs "2".

Seems the time is 2:12PM, which would give that exact output.